# Why is the result of TrueQ[(x^n)^m == x^(n*m)] False?

Tags: algebra, boolean-computation

Why is the result of the code below `False` ?

```
TrueQ[(x^n)^m == x^(n*m)]
```

How can I get it to be `True`?

Comment: Try `TrueQ[PowerExpand[(x^n)^m] == x^(n*m)]`  because TrueQ  checks structural sameness  for True to show up. not mathematical sameness

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is that you did not feed to `Mathematica` any assumptions.

Check for example `FullSimplify`:

```
FullSimplify[(x^n)^m == x^(n*m)]
```

It just returns the input, whereas

```
FullSimplify[(x^n)^m == x^(n*m),
 Assumptions -> {x ∈ PositiveReals,
   n ∈ PositiveReals, m ∈ PositiveReals}]
```

yields

> `True`

So, if executing

```
TrueQ[(x^n)^m == x^(n*m) //
  FullSimplify[#,
    Assumptions -> {x ∈ PositiveReals,
      n ∈ PositiveReals, m ∈ PositiveReals}] &]
```

you have your answer.

I saw [the comment by Nasser](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/295725/why-result-of-trueqxnm-xnm-is-false/295726#comment732117_295725) and this is an attempt at further pedagogy.

From the documentation of [**`PowerExpand`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand.html)

> `The transformations made by PowerExpand are correct in general only if`
> `is an integer or  and  are positive real numbers.`

Thanks to [Daniel Lichtblau for the comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/295725/why-result-of-trueqxnm-xnm-is-false/295726#comment732142_295726). I am literally copying it and pasting it here for completeness:

> `PowerExpand` also takes `Assumptions`. If they are not the default, it will not make further assumptions (so you don’t need to guess if True is really true, for this example)

Comment: This is all on target, but I will point out that PowerExpand also takes Assumptions. If they are not the default, it will not make further assumptions (so you don’t need to guess if True is really true, for this example).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau thanks a lot for the comment. I have updated the answer

Comment: `Simplify[(x^n)^m==x^(n*m),Assumptions->{x∈PositiveReals,n∈Reals,m∈ Reals}]` also works.

Answer (score 9):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use [`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) to find counterexamples

```
FindInstance[(x^n)^m != x^(n*m), {m, n, x}, 5]

(* {{m -> -(439/5) - (334 I)/5, n -> -(13/10) + (371 I)/5, 
  x -> 313/5 + 123 I}, {m -> -(171/10) + (36 I)/5, n -> 5 + (457 I)/10, 
  x -> 331/10 - (449 I)/5}, {m -> 297/10 + (384 I)/5, n -> 8 - 73 I, 
  x -> 38/5 + (249 I)/2}, {m -> -(464/5) + (409 I)/10, n -> 72 + (413 I)/10, 
  x -> 949/10 + (89 I)/2}, {m -> 41/10 - (213 I)/2, 
  n -> -(363/10) + (576 I)/5, x -> -(267/5) - (1043 I)/10}} *)
```

Integer exponents are required:

```
Assuming[{m, n} ∈ Integers, (x^n)^m == x^(n*m) // Simplify]

(* True *)
```

For example,

```
(x^n)^m == x^(n*m) /. {m -> 2, n -> -3, x -> 5 + 7 I}

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 4):

No one has yet has answered the first question as stated. I realize the second question probably is more important to the OP. But if the working of `TrueQ` had been understood, the question but should be:

*The question not asked:*

> Why doesn't `(x^n)^m == x^(n*m)` evaluate to `True`?

See other answers. I will add that `Equal` does minimal work to determine whether an equality is true: for instance, `(x - 1) (x + 1) == x^2 - 1`.

*The question asked:*

> Why doesn't `TrueQ[(x^n)^m == x^(n*m)]` evaluate to `True`?

Because `(x^n)^m == x^(n*m)` doesn't evaluate to `True`. The purpose of `TrueQ`, which was obscure to me for the first couple of years I was using *Mathematica*, is to test whether a result returns the symbol `True` or something else. This is useful when a check might have three outcomes: `True`, `False`, or "other" such as "cannot be determined," "not always true (or false)."

Thus `TrueQ[expr]` is `True` exactly when `expr` has evaluated to the symbol `True`; otherwise, it returns `False`. It makes no attempt to determine whether `expr` is a true expression. Only whether it has already been determined to be true; or more precisely, whether it has evaluated to `True`, since it cannot determine whether the correct answer has been computed.

The second question, "How to get `True`?", has already been answered, and the answer is implied by the above: Pass `TrueQ` the result of calculating whether `(x^n)^m == x^(n*m)` is true. Others have already shown it's not true for all values of `x`, `m`, and `n` and that assumptions need to be added to a function like `Simplify` to get the desired result.